# You can pay by credit card or "by" cash

Tags: conjunctions

Which one of the following is correct?

> - You can pay by credit card or by cash.
> - You can pay by credit card or cash.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either one is arguably correct: [if the two items take the same preposition, you don't have to repeat it](https://www.grammarly.com/handbook/sentences/parallelism/2/parallelism-with-prepositions/), and it's actually slightly more fluent-sounding not to repeat it.  For example,

- I am going to the museum and (to) the zoo.
- Julia was accompanied by Arnold and (by) Zoe.

However, "pay by cash" isn't very common; [we usually say you pay **with** cash or **in** cash.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pay+by+cash%2Cpay+with+cash%2Cpay+in+cash&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpay%20by%20cash%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpay%20with%20cash%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpay%20in%20cash%3B%2Cc0)

[It's also possible to say "pay **with a** credit card."](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pay%20by%20credit%20card%2Cpay%20with%20credit%20card%2Cpay%20with%20a%20credit%20card&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpay%20by%20credit%20card%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpay%20with%20credit%20card%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpay%20with%20a%20credit%20card%3B%2Cc0)  So other possible alternatives are

- You can pay by credit card or with cash.
- You can pay by credit card or in cash.
- You can pay with a credit card or cash.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of common usage it's often shortened to just "cash or card", so you'll probably most often hear "You can pay by cash or card" in shops. Sometimes a cashier will just look at a customer and ask "cash or card?" as the whole sentence.

If you're asking whether "by" fits cash as well, ask yourself what cash & credit card are - they're payment methods **by** which someone will pay. So you're essentially informing someone to pay by the method called cash or by the method called credit card.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thought:

Though it's right to say pay by card or in cash, I think it would make sense to use with, however, such sentence would certainly be very strange. Here's my reasoning:

By is used to talk about the method, or how we got the result. Whereas with is used to talk about the tool used to get the result.

That said, our result is the payment, and we can get there by either using a tool or a means. So, in theory, this makes sense, but of course as it's been stated earlier, the most common is by card and in cash :)

Comment: What you say about “by” seems a little oversimplified. Some dictionaries list [more than a dozen definitions](https://www.wordnik.com/words/by) for the preposition.

Comment: So if I understood your reasoning correct, my sentence that I wrote before googling the question should be correct "Pay by Credit/Debit Card with Stripe" referring here t Credit/Debit card as the method and Stripe (the payment processor) as the tool. I feel it could also be argued the other way around Stripe as the method and the card as the tool, but the first option sounds better. Stripe is defiantly a tool.